# Proving that I can write $a(\geq 1$ in base $b(\geq 2)$

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Question:

Suppose that $a\geq 1$ and $b\geq 2$. Show that there exist $a_0,a_1,...,a_d \in [0,b-1]$, such that
$a=a_d b^d+a_{d-1}b^{d-1}+....+a_0$

I tried to approach the problem using the Euclidean algorithm.

Suppose I take any integer $b$ greater than $2$. Then, if for a given $a\geq 1$, if $1   \leq a\leq b-1$, then we can write a=(0)b+a and the whole thing gets done.

The case $a \geq b$ has gotten very complicated for me.

By Euclidean Algorithm, we can write $a$ as,
$a=bq_1+r_1$ where $0 \leq r_1\leq b-1<a$.Thus, $a-r$ is positive, and consequently, $q_1$ is positive. If $q_1 \in [0,b-1]$, our job is done. If $q_1\geq b$, then by  perceiving $a=q_1$ as repeating the same thing we did with $a$, we go on obtaining $q_i$ such that,
$q_i=q_{i+1}b+r_{i+1}$, where $r_{i+1} \in [0,b-1]$ unless at some point $q_i$ becomes less than $b$ for some $i$. Also,$q_{i+1}<bq_{i+1}+r_{i+1}=q_i$. So, this process will end in finite number of steps.

My approach is rather intuitive and I am struggling to write this formally.Can somebody help me prove case 2 more formally by using only the Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: By strong induction you can write $q_1$ in radix $b,\,$ so ditto for $\,bq_1 + r_1 = a.\,$ Said *algorithmically*, recurse on $q_1$ then leftshift the result and append the unit digit $r_1.\ $ You're using "division with remainder", not the Euclidean (gcd) algorithm.

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is introduce what $d$ is.  As $1 < b < b^2 < ..... $ and $b^k$ is unbounded then for any $a\ge 1$ there is a unique $d$ so that $b^d \le a < b^{d+1}$.  So there exist by division with remainder an $a_d$ so that $a = a_db^d + r_d$ were $0 \le r_d < b^d$.  Then go.... down (not up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to start from the top and go down than to start from the bottom and go up.

We can do it your way and end up with a bunch of equations

$a= q_1b + r_1; a_0 = r_1$
$q_1 = q_2b + r_2; a_1 = r_2$
$q_2 = q_3b + r_3;a_2=r_3$
.....  until it ends .....
$q_{d-1}= q_db + r_d;a_{d-1}=r_3$ (but $q_d < b$ for the first time and so)
$q_d = 0\cdot b + q_d = 0\cdot b + r_{d+1}$ and $a_d=q_d = r_{d+1}$.

but then you have to show that:

$a = q_1b + a_0 =$
$(q_2b + a_1)b + a_0 =$
$....$
$(((((((((((a_db + a_{d-1})b + a_{d-2})b + .....  +a_2)b+a_1)b + a_0=$
$adb^d + a_{d-1}b^{d-1} + ..... + a_2b^2 + a_1b + a_0$.

... but that requires a lot of inductive faith and hand waving.

Better to determine that as $1 < b < b^2 < b^3 < .....$ is unbounded then if we assume $a\ge b$  (if we assume $a < b$ then we just let $a_0 = a$ and we are done) then there is a unique $d$ so that $b^d \le a < b^{d+1}$.

And therefore we can find unique

$a = a_db^d + r_d$ where $0 \le r_d < b^d$ and $1 \le a_d \le b-1$.    Then as $a = a_db^d + r_d < b^{d+1}$ we have unique values where

$r_d = a_{d-1}b^{d-1} + r_{d-1}$ where $0 \le r_d < b^{d-1}$ and $0 \le a_{d-1}\le b-1$.  And we repeat.

As each step reduces our our case to $r_{d-k}$ where $0\le r_{d-k} < b^{d-k-1}$ we will after $d$ steps reach:

$r_3 = a_2b^2 + r_2$ where $0\le r_d < b^2$ and $0 \le a_2 \le b-1$
$r_2 = a_1b + r_1$ where $0\le r_1 < b$ and $0 \le a_1 \le b-1$
$r_1 = 0\cdot b + r_0$ where $r_0 = r_1 = a_0$ and as $0 \le a_0 < b$ we have $0 \le a_0\le b-1$.